# how can pass buildroot to build.xml file from spec file

Tags: ant, specifications, rpm-spec

*can anyone help , passing argument as build-root or dynamic directory using ant command in spec file

*mentioning ant install target in build.xml

```
<target name="install"/>
   <copy todir="${build-root}/some_location >
      <fileset dir="lib/*.jar"/>
   </copy>
</target>
```

- copy all jar files to location build-root/some_location.
- here build-root have to get from spec file

spec file:

%install
ant install

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your ${build-root} property from commandline either use :

```
ant -f build.xml -Dbuild-root=/some/path
```

or create a file with [property format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)), means key=value, f.e. :

```
foo=bar
somevalue=somekey
build-root=/some/path
...
```

and use it from commandline :

```
ant -f build.xml -propertyfile yourfile.properties
```

Also possible are combinations of several -Dkey=value and -propertyfile Parameters :

```
ant -f build.xml -Dfoo=bar -Dfooo=baz -propertfile foo.properties -propertyfile foo.properties
```

Don't know nothing about spec but from your posting it looks like the line

```
%install ant install
```

means [%install = spec Parameter ?] ant -f build.xml install (= targetname in build.xml)
-f build.xml is obsolete when filename build.xml in current directory

and something like that may work :

```
%install ant install -Dbuild-root=/some/path
```

or :

```
%install ant install -propertyfile foo.properties
```

See [ant manual commandline](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline)